# How do I build service that accepts name and values through POST in c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, soa

I found out WCF does not accept POST requests. I know REST architecture does. What would  the process and the service look like for building something like this:
client code sends data to the server through POST method.

The data contains name=john&age=20&country=USA

and the service response is xml file content. I looked at WCF rest components but i am worried it required client code to reference the service. I do not want the client to add service reference. In fact service should not be aware of any technology the client is written in. All it cares is it is receiving above data through POST and it responds with xml file content.

Comment: Sounds like you need a REST interface.  There are a number of ways to achieve that.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: What about any old web server that gets the data via a POST request and outputs XML in the HTTP response?  Or do you have other requirements that would require more of a framework?

Comment: I would look into Asp.Net WEB API

Comment: Thanks guys I am going through the recommended links and will update this post later.

Comment: MVC4 web api ended up working for me. Again thanks a lot.